# Best python data structure to replace values in a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

I am working with a dataframe where I need to replace values in 1 column. My natural instinct is to go towards a python dictionary HOWEVER, this is an example of what my data looks like (original_col):

```
original_col  desired_col
cat           animal
dog           animal
bunny         animal
cat           animal
chair         furniture
couch         furniture
Bob           person
Lisa          person
```

A dictionary would look something like:

```
my_dict: {'animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny'], 'furniture': ['chair', 'couch'], 'person': ['Bob', 'Lisa']}
```

I can't use the typical my_dict.get() since I am looking to retrieve corresponding KEY rather than the value. Is dictionary the best data structure? Any suggestions?

Comment: you need the *reverse* mapping then.

Answer (score 0):

flip your dictionary:

```
my_new_dict = {v: k for k, vals in my_dict.items() for v in vals}
```

note, this will not work if you have values like: `dog->animal, dog->person`

Answer (score 0):

[`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) already accepts a dictionary in a specific structure so you don't need to re-invent the wheel: `{col_name: {old_value: new_value}}`

```
df.replace({'original_col': {'cat': 'animal', 'dog': 'animal', 'bunny': 'animal',
                             'chair': 'furniture', 'couch': 'furniture', 
                             'Bob': 'person', 'Lisa': 'person'}})
```

Alternatively you could use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), then only the inner dictionary is required:

```
df['original_col'].replace({'cat': 'animal', 'dog': 'animal', 'bunny': 'animal',
                            'chair': 'furniture', 'couch': 'furniture', 
                            'Bob': 'person', 'Lisa': 'person'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas `map()` function uses a dictionary or another pandas Series to perform this kind of lookup, IIUC:

```
# original column / data
data = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'cat', 'chair', 'couch', 'Bob', 'Lisa']

# original dict
my_dict: {'animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny'], 
          'furniture': ['chair', 'couch'], 
          'person': ['Bob', 'Lisa']
         }

# invert the dictionary
new_dict = { v: k 
             for k, vs in my_dict.items()
             for v in vs }

# create series and use `map()` to perform dictionary lookup
df = pd.concat([
    pd.Series(data).rename('original_col'),
    pd.Series(data).map(new_values).rename('desired_col')], axis=1)

print(df)

  original_col desired_col
0          cat      animal
1          dog      animal
2        bunny      animal
3          cat      animal
4        chair   furniture
5        couch   furniture
6          Bob      person
7         Lisa      person
```